# Laravel 5 form request validation with ID - show

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am wanting to validate a resource controller in Laravel, so that the user can only access `clinic.show` if they're the owner of said clinic.

I correctly validated this using the following:

```
public function show($id)
{
    if (Clinic::where('id', $id)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->exists()) {
        return View::make('clinic.show', ['clinic' => Clinic::where('id', $id)
                     ->first()]);
} else {
    abort(401, 'Unauthorized action.');
}

}
```

However, I believe this is bad practice and I should be using the `Form Request` feature within Laravel.

I have created a `ShowClinicFormRequest.php` and added the following code:

```
public function authorize()
{

    $clinicId = $this->route('clinic');

    return Clinic::where('id', $clinicId)
    ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->exists();
}
```

And within the show function -

```
public function show($id, ShowClinicFormRequest $request)
{
    return View::make('clinic.show', ['clinic' => Clinic::where('id', $id)->first()]);
}
```

However, the error that I am getting is:

> ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 53: Class
>   App\Http\Controllers\ShowClinicFormRequest does not exist

It obviously doesn't exist within that directory because it isn't a controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your form request is located in the `App\Http\Requests` namespace so you need to import the class or use explicitly:

```
use App\Http\Requests\ShowClinicFormRequest;
```

or just

```
public function show($id, \App\Http\Requests\ShowClinicFormRequest $request)
{}
```

You might also to take a look at filters or [middlewares](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware).